# Least square solution equals solution for consistent linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove for consistent linear system $Ax=b$. The least square solution (given by $\{x\mid A^T Ax=A^T b\}$) equals the solution($\{x\mid Ax=b\}$).

Easy to show that solution is a subset of least square solution.

Also easy to show that If $AA^T$ is invertible, $A(A^{T}Ax)=AA^T b\Rightarrow Ax=b$.

But how can I show that least square solution is a subset of solution if $AA^T$ is not invertible? Or $AA^T$ can never be not invertible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AA^T$ is invertible if and only if $A$ has full rank (full row rank in your case).  As you are talking about least squares I assume that you are over the reals, in this case $AA^T$ is positive definite (and hence invertible) as long as $A$ has full row rank.

As a non full row rank in a consistent system would mean that some of the equations are superfluous these rows would just be left out, so that you could (after applying this fix) always assume that $AA^T$ is invertible.

Comment: As a starter on linear algebra, I cannot get the concept of positive definite...could you please elaborate on this and why positive definite means invertible?

Comment: A matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is called positive definite, if for any row vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$ we have $xMx^T > 0$.
Thus $xM$ is always non zero, hence $M$ has trivial kernel and is thus invertible.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's best to think of least squares solutions as minimizers of $\| Ax - b \|_2$.

I'll assume that $A$ is a real $m \times n$ matrix and that the linear system $Ax = b$ is consistent.

Let $S = \arg \, \min_x \| Ax - b \|_2$.  In other words, $S$ is the set of all minimizers (with respect to $x$) of $\| Ax - b \|_2$.  Certainly any solution to $Ax = b$ belongs to $S$.  Conversely, if $x \in S$, then $\| Ax - b \|_2 = 0$, so $Ax = b$.

Therefore, $S$ is equal to $\{ x \mid Ax = b \}$.